# Black recording screen UI in Xcode instruments

Tags: xcode5, xcode-instruments

Whenever I try to profile my application using instruments, the main panel gets blocked by a black screen saying "Recording".

I can't configure instruments while I am profiling or see any measurements that are being taken. Once I stop recording, I can see the profiling results.

Is there any way to remove this screen? I have attached a screenshot of what instruments looks like.

I am running Xcode 5.0 with Instruments 5.0.

[image]

Comment: ran into same issue here. Xcode 6.2, 6.3.

Comment: same issue Xcode 7.2.1. @fangmobile.com Did you solve this?